# PowerBI : Result based on a sub-query

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have two tables that contains a  commun column.
TableA : Id, Phone
TableB : ID, Phone, Adress, Volume ...

I want to do a filter, so that only rows in tableB which are not in tableA must be displayed.

Here is the query I want to use :

```
select count(phone) from tableB where phone not in (select phone from tableA)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your table and count the rows:

```
PhoneCount = COUNTROWS(
                 FILTER(tableB,
                     NOT(tableB[phone] IN VALUES(tableA[phone]))
                 )
             )
```

---

Note: Older versions of DAX that don't allow the `IN` syntax can use the equivalent `CONTAINS` function formulation. See [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly what I wanted to do.